# CloudFoundry UAA Multi instances

Tags: cloud-foundry, federated-identity, cloudfoundry-uaa

What’s the recommended setup across CloudFoundry foundations for UAA? When clients can get routed between the foundations how are clients ensured they don't get re-authenticate?
More specifically: If an access/id token is generated in one foundation can it be used in the other foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that clients do not have to re-authenticate across multiple UAAs, you will have to ensure that the JWT signing key is the same in each foundation. You probably also want to make sure that the `issuer` field (`properties.uaa.issuer` in the BOSH deployment) is the same, though I'm less sure that that's required.